# Bootstrap - .container-fluid inside .container-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap 5, when I do:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: lime;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color: red;">
       <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the second container is not 100% width.

I can read the following in the [official docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/#how-they-work):

> .container-fluid, which is width: 100% at all breakpoints

So... why does this happen?

Comment: `.container-fluid` has padding left and right f 12px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after inspecting your code it appears that the `.container-fluid` has right and left padding:

```
.container, .container-fluid, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * .5);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

this was the code, try doing the following in your css and hopefully your div will take up the 100% width like you need it to, replace it with this:

```
.container, .container-fluid, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

if adding the `padding-right: 0;` and `padding-left: 0;` doesnt fix your problem then try:

```
.container, .container-fluid, .container-lg, .container-md, .container-sm, .container-xl, .container-xxl {
    --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```